# How can i join various CSV files into only one in same row comma separated?

Tags: csv, paste, ls

I have more or less 100 CSV files and i want to join all of them in the same file.csv, in the same row and ordered by modification date.

Actually I use `paste -d, *.csv > out.csv` but the files are named like this:

sample_1

And it orders the content like this:

```
sample_100
sample_101
sample_102
...
sample_10
sample_110
sample_111
...
```

The desired order is:

```
sample_1
sample_2
sample_3
...
sample_100
```

The solution can be order by modification date by I dont know how,
maybe something like `ls -latr | paste -d, *.csv > out.csv`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in $(ls -t); do  paste -d, $i >> out.csv; done
```

ls -t : will list the files and order them by modification time.

">>" : instead of > to concatenate and not erase previous content

I tested it locally and it works well for me.

Comment: It gives the output CSV file with the content in the same column, how can i put it in the same row?

Comment: `sed  's/^|$/\x27/g' out.csv | paste -sd, > out2.csv` after your command and its okey Thanks!